# ClientDataset Aggregates distinct

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a `ClientDataSet` with one aggregate field that computes the average over another field. I also have an Index on a "Group" field. The result after running the aggregate looks like this - so far so good:
[image]

What I would like to achieve is to reduce the aggregate to one row per group, like this:[image]

I tried filtering, but obviously this can't work. I also tried to clone the cursor to a new dataset with an unique index on Group, but also with no luck. It seems as if the Index on the new `ClientDataSet` is just ignored, although I cloned the cursor resetting the Index Fields of the first `ClientDataSet`: 
`ClientDataSet2.CloneCursor(ClientDataset1, True, False);`

So, any good ideas how to achieve this are much appreciated.

EDIT: Just realised, that the Avg Values changed in the second screenshot. Of course I would like to preserve the original values from the first screenshot.

Comment: What do you expect to see in the val column when only one row per group is shown?

Comment: @UweRaabe, the val column is not important. It doesn't matter if I see the first middle or last entry. What matters is that I have one Group and one average value. In the end I want to show the values in a chart, if that helps to understand my question.

Comment: @UweRaabe just like what from `select Group, avg(val) from CDS group by Group` would result.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with an easy solution. 
*Just a thought:* I think you need to populate a new dataset each time values are changed in order to reflect the `Avg/Group`. your new dataset will consist of Group and AvgVal. so you iterate your original CDS and check for `gbFirst in ClientDataSet1.GetGroupState(1)` if it is true you add a new record. an alternative would be to "group" your display like this: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/29272/IMAGE15.JPG

Comment: Here is the reference: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29272

Comment: @kobik, I know all the articles from Cary Jensen, very good indeed. Unfortunately this doesn't help in my situation.

Comment: Have you read my previous comment?

Comment: @kobik, Yes I did and I think something along those lines is the only possible solution. I had hoped there would be a simpler solution, but in the end, to know that there isn't keeps me from spending more time into this.